# Integration React Native into existing iOS app via CocoaPods - Unable to build UIKit, CoreFoundation

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I am currently trying to integrate React-Native into the app by making it a component pod as mentioned at:
[https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/04/17/making-a-components-pod/](http://Making%20a%20Components%20Pod%20like%20Emission%20by%20Artsy)

I am able to get it working for the flow mentioned by them. But when implementing it in a legacy codebase I am seeing issues

**Some details on the codebase:**
 - Mix of ObjC and Swift.
 - Uses CocoaPods for third party dependencies.

**Issue I am facing** 
 - Unable to build system frameworks/modules like `UIKit` in my bridging header for `string.h` as well as in `Folly` (seeing in the screenshot below). Happens to `CoreFoundation`, `Darwin` as well.

[image: Screenshot of issue navigator]

Contents of Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

def shared_pods
    pod 'AFNetworking', '3.1'
    pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger.git', :branch => '3_0_0'    
    pod 'AppsFlyerFramework'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
    pod 'KeychainAccess'
    pod 'LGSemiModalNavController', '0.2.0'
    pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 2.2'
    pod 'MZFormSheetPresentationController', '~> 2.4.2'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7.2'
    pod 'TRVSDictionaryWithCaseInsensitivity', '0.0.2'
    pod 'SwiftLint'
    pod 'SwiftMoment'

    # React Native Support
    plugin 'cocoapods-fix-react-native'
    pod 'GitDawg', :path => '../GitDawg'
    pod 'React', :podspec => 'Local Pods/React.podspec.json'
    pod 'yoga',  :podspec => 'Local Pods/yoga.podspec.json'
end

target 'RedMart' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'RedMartAlphaTests' do
    shared_pods
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
    end
  end
end
```

The RN components come from the `GitDawg` pod.

Comment: Show pod file. Show folder structure and where React Native files are in relation to project

Comment: @agibson007 Updated with podfile contents. GitDawg Pod containing RN component is present at adjacent folder.